# How to compile SQLCipher for Android as a static executable?

Tags: android, sqlcipher

Just wondering whether it is possible to compile [SQLCipher for Android](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher) as a static executable ? If possible how can I do it

Thanks

Comment: What do mean "static executable"?

Comment: binary that i can run via shell

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to run SQLCipher as a command line shell, we have basic build instructions available [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/introduction/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am trying to build sqlcipher cli for Android. Android build instructions in your link are for precompiled .so library files. Building sqlcipher as a cli for Android seems very challenging job. I have downloaded SQLite source code and enabled SQLITE_HAS_CODEC SQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 flags. When i compile it is complaining about missing functions. Eg: sqlite3CodecGetKey. Can you give me few points on how enable sqlchiper and build it as an executable for Android ? Thanks